# DNS Delegation Records

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I'm currently studying for my Active Directory exam and am a little confused with relation to how DNS Delegation works - mainly in this example.

I have two domains in a forest - `contoso.com` and `nwtraders.com`

In the Contoso DNS, there is a Forward Lookup Zone (`FLZ`) with a delegation pointing at NWtraders so that anyone in the Contoso zone can resolve NWtraders DNS queries. Which is fine and makes perfect sense to me.

The question is: is the delegation two ways, since how can NWTraders computers and users resolve Contoso IP addresses and host names, there is no entry in NWTraders DNS which forwards or points to Contoso in anyway?

Comment: The same way folks around the world can find `serverfault.com` without any special configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If a stub zone is needed to resolve the name, then there's something funky about the DNS structure.  They're essentially overriding normal delegation rules.

A normal delegation from Contoso would need to be in Contoso's zone, so like `nwtraders.contoso.com`.  Inserting a stub zone of `nwtraders.com` overrides the normal process of a lookup against the root servers for the `.com` zone, then the `.com` servers for the `nwtraders` zone.

If the `nwtraders` zone has no similar stub zone, then their lookups for the `contoso.com` zone will function as normal, using the public DNS delegation structure.